# bubble sort not working with dynamic memory allocation in C

Tags: c

I was making a program using dynamic memory allocation that can rearrange the elements of the array. But it is giving the wrong results.

Here is my Code :

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int bubble_sort(int n,int *ar)
 {
    int i=0,j=0,temp;
    for(i; i<n;i++)
    {
        for(j; j<n-i-1;j++)
        {
            if(*(ar + j)>*(ar + j + 1))
            {
                temp = *(ar + j);
                 *(ar + j) = *(ar + j + 1);
                *(ar + j + 1) = temp;
            }
        }
    }

}
 main()
{
    int n,i;
    printf("Enter the size of the array : ");
   scanf("%d",&n);
    int *arr1 = (int *)calloc(n,sizeof(int));
    printf("Enter the elements of first array : \n");
     for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",(arr1+i));
        printf("\n");
    }
    bubble_sort(n,arr1);
    printf("After sorting, array is : \n");
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    { 
        printf("%d\t",*(arr1 + i));
    }
}
```

The output it gives is just a random set of numbers that I enter as elements of the array.

For example, if I enter the number of elements of array as 6 and then the elements as

```
7, 8, 9, 5, 6, 4
```

then the output is

```
7, 8, 5, 6, 4, 9
```

Comment: Please get rid of the manual input but use hardcoded values for the example here. Firstly, it rules out errors there. Secondly, it makes it easier for others to reproduce your problem and gets the code overall closer to the required MCVE.

Comment: Note: `*(ar + j)` is the same as `ar[j]`. Saves some typing and makes the code easier to read.

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*  2) separate functions by 2 or 3 blank lines (be consistent)  3) separate code blocks ( `for` `if` `else` `while` `do...while` `switch` `case` `default` ) via a single blank line 4) consistently indent the code: indent after every opening brace '{'.  unindent before every closing brace '}.  Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces. 5) use meaningful variable names

Comment: There are only two valid signatures for the function: `main()`.  They both have a return type of `int` I.E. `int main( void )` and `int main( int argc, char *argv[] )`

Comment: regarding: `for(i; i<n;i++)`  the first parameter does nothing beyond causing the compiler to output a warning message.  Suggest: `for( ; i<n; i++ )`

Comment: for ease of readability, suggest: insert an appropriate space: inside parens, after commas, after semicolons, around C operators

Comment: in general, it is good programming practice to limit the 'scope' of variables.  suggest removing the statement: `int i=0,j=0,temp;` and declaring the variables `i` and `j` in the `for()` statements and declaring `temp` as the first line of the `if()` code block

Comment: statements like: `if(*(ar + j)>*(ar + j + 1))` can be greatly simplified to `if( ar[ j] > ar[ j+1] )`

Comment: when calling any of the heap allocation functions: ( malloc, calloc, realloc ) 1) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  2) the returned type is `void*` so can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting just clutters the code, making it more difficult to understand, debug, etc

Comment: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions: always check the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  In the current scenario, any returned value other than 1 indicates an error occurred.  Note: failures of the input/conversion specifications does not effect 'errno' so need to use `fprintf( stderr, "...\n");` kind of statements to report the problem to `stderr`

Comment: the signature for the `bubble_sort()` function claims that the function returns an `int`.  However, it does not.  Suggest changing the returned type to `void`

Comment: the posted code is depending on the OS to cleanup after the program exits.  This is a poor programming practice.  In the current code, cleanup by inserting: `free( arr1 );`  just before the final closing brace in `main()`

Answer (score 1):

you need to start j at 0 each time through the outer loop, change

```
for(j; j<n-i-1;j++)
```

to

```
for(j=0; j<n-i-1; j++)
```

In general it is best to initialize the counter variable within the for loop to avoid confusion about its range and avoid bugs like this.  So even

```
int i=0;
for(i; i<n;i++)
```

would be better written as

```
int i;
for(i=0; i<n;i++)
```

or even better (for modern C compilers)

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
```

Answer (score 0):

`for(j; j<n-i-1;j++)` will be `for(j=0; j<n-i-1;j++)` this `j=0` is needed as you will start comparing from beginning again.

Also the `for` loop of `i` will be `for(i; i<n-1;i++)`.(This is done because the `i=n-1` will never make the inner loop run- it's redundant to iterate one more time)(You have initialized `i` with `0` outside the block so `i=0` not needed and can be skipped) This is the right way to do and this gives you the desired output.

The initialization of `i` should be moved to `for` loop as pointed by Tom Karzes, it is much cleaner design and good practice. Also think of it, when you declare local variables out of the scope where you use it - it is much harder to control and keep track of. Even you declare it outside the `for`  block assign the value `0` inside the for loop also.`for(i =0;...)` or  `for(int i=0; ...)` is a good way to go.

There are couple of things `*(arr+i)` is same as `arr[i]`. Don't make things harder to read than it should be. `calloc`'s return value should be checked and the memory allocated should be free when you are done working with it.

Comment: The initialization of `i` should be moved to the `for` loop.  It's functionally equivalent, but much better style.  Decoupling the initialization of the induction variable from the loop is bad style when avoidable.

Comment: @TomKarzes.: Thanks for pointing out and yes it is better. I edited it.